# Set levels in scale_fill_distiller

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am trying to control the levels set by ggplot2 scale_fill_distiller, ideally I would like to show the lower levels of "values" better. The plot below shows no variation - I suppose - because the numbers are close to 0.

The data is hosted here:
http://pasted.co/4aa6411c

And I am plotting with:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(Years, Age, fill = values)) + geom_tile() + 
scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral")
```

Which gives the result:

[image]

Comment: Would transforming the scale be another option? E.g. `ggplot(data, aes(Years, Age, fill = values)) + geom_tile() + 
scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", trans = "log10")`.

Comment: I suppose, but to be honest it bugs me that there isn't a simple options for "forcing" it the way I want

Comment: You could also define custom values and rescale them like e.g. `ggplot(data, aes(Years, Age, fill = values)) + geom_tile() + 
scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", values = scales::rescale((1:10)^4, c(0,1)))`.

Comment: I like the log idea, but its not really clear (to me) what rescales does exactly - in this case